# COM Object created in C# return "Access to the path is denied." in Windows Authentication" mode

Tags: authentication, anonymous, comobject

I have a problem with configuration IIS 10. I have site running on VBScript installed in the default wwwroot folder (C:\inetpub\wwwroot).

The site uses external COM Object created in C#, which tried to use one folder to read/write file into.

Library is registered via Visual Studio, use "Register for COM interop".

The problems start appearing when it needs to read file from disk "c:\Share...", code return : "Access to the path is denied."

Site using the 'Classic ASP' application pool which in turn is using the 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' identity and Authentication type is selected: "Windows Authentication" other are disabled.
The logs indicate that the system does not have permission to write to the file system.

I have applied different combinations of write / modify / full permissions for different user accounts including the 'IIS AppPool\Clasic ASP' , 'IUSR', and 'IIS_IUSRS' group for folder "C:\Share..." but it didn't help.

It works in case I select Authentication type : Anonymous Authentication, but site should be run in Windows Authentication mode.